# The SSL Connection could not be established - .NET 6

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, .net-6.0

Problem with SSL:

> The SSL connection could not be established

My .NET 6 project do requests to an API, in a development environment everything works fine, but in the production server I get this error The SSL connection could not be established when the program executes the request, both, the project and the API are in the same server with https protocol.

I have already tried things like this:

```
httpClientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual; 
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslpolicyerrros) => { return true; };

// httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback 
// = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;

client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(correo), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response = await client.PostAsync(routeApi, content);
```

And unfortunately didn't work. Have you faced a problem like this before? How did you solve it?

Comment: What TLS version does your server use?

Comment: This is very likely not an issue with your code but a connectivity issue. Most common cause would be mismatched cipher suites or firewall dropping connections for some reason.

Comment: @PoulBak I don't really know , let me ask for it!

Comment: @JohnWu It makes sense, because I have tried everything, I'll look around there. Thank you.

Comment: "The SSL connection could not be established" what's the rest of the error?